# How can I mathematically model a pringle as a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, quadrics

I need to translate the dimensions of a pringle chip into a mathematical function to calculate the surface area of hyperbolic paraboloids. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you actually know what the dimensions of a pringle chip are or are we looking at doing this abstractly?

Comment: We are assuming that we know the length and height of the pringle.

Comment: Using a graphing calculator and augmented reality to measure the coefficents: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_X5SNtS3cl8 we arrived at values of $z=\frac{x^2}{4.6}-\frac{y^2}{5.9}, 0.67 x^2+y^2<4$

Answer (score 6):

Try playing with $$z=\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}$$ for various positive values of $a,b$ in the disk given by $$x^2+y^2< 1 $$and zoom in near the origin as needed. It will look like this:

[image]

To find it's surface area, [use the procedure given here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx) with $f=1$ and maybe parametrize the region above (disk) using polar coordinates. The explanation in the link is pretty detailed.

Comment: So if I have a pringle with me, how can I figure out the exact values of a and b?