# How to calculate surface of area with given equations $x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2$ and $az = xy$

Tags: analysis, surfaces, parametrization

For $a>0$ I'm trying to calculate the surface of area with given equations $x^2 + y^2 \leq a$ and $az = xy$.

I think it should be done with $$\iint_D |\vec{r_u} \times \vec{r_v}| \,du\,dv $$, which is the surface of $\Sigma$ with the regular parametrization $\vec{r}: D \rightarrow \Sigma,  \vec{r}(u,v) = (X(u,v), Y(u,v), Z(u,v))$.

I get that the surface is (if I'm not wrong) an intersection of a cylinder and a hyperbolic paraboloid, but kind of got stuck when trying to find a parametrization of the surface. Any hints would be very appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: Not inside of a sphere. In 3-d, $x^2+y^2 \le a$ is a cylinder.

Comment: Thank you, just fixed it, had some problems with wording what I thought. And now it also seems, that cylindric coordinates should do the trick. Thank you! I was just making it way too complicated in my head :)

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976693/how-can-i-mathematically-model-a-pringle-as-a-function) has a nice image (rotated $45^\circ$)